# DataFrame column of Lists and NaN to String

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I try to convert a DataFrame Column of Lists to String. The Column contains of Lists and NaN Values

Table:

```
id  col_list 
1   ['Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 'Donec non sem convallis', 'vulputate odio']
2   NaN
3   ['Mauris diam purus',  'luctus in rutrum venenatis', 'eros in luctus lobortis']
4   ['Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet']
```

Output:

```
id  col_list 
1   'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Donec non sem convallis, vulputate odio'
2   NaN
3   'Mauris diam purus, luctus in rutrum venenatis, eros in luctus lobortis
4   'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'
```

Following approach throws this error message

```
 df['col_list'] = [','.join(elems) for elems in df['col_list']]

TypeError: can only join an iterable
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `apply`:

```
mask = ~df['col_list'].isna()
df.loc[mask , 'col_list'] = df.loc[mask, 'col_list'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x))
#or
df.loc[mask, 'col_list'] = [','.join(elems) for elems in df.loc[mask, 'col_list']]
```

Comment: I get following error: TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, dict found

Comment: @jonas Can you paste `df.to_dict()` to see how the data is?

Answer (score 1):

Filter `NaN` by using `dropna` and `agg.join` and assign back:

```
df['col_list'] = df.col_list.dropna().agg(', '.join)

Out[205]:
   id                                                                col_list
0   1     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Donec non sem convallis, vulputate odio
1   2                                                                     NaN
2   3  Mauris diam purus, luctus in rutrum venenatis, eros in luctus lobortis
3   4                                              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
```

Comment: I get following error: TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, dict found


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:


TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found

Comment: @jonas: it means your real dataset has some lists contains `dict` instead of strings. You need to find those rows and think how to handle them.